# How do I gain access to editable in event object via getEventById in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar-6

The relevant code and the console output is shown below. Naturally, the code line numbers are shown in the log. I did not paste all the code, given the size! However, it did not seem the correct response I should get from getEventById. When I added an `alert(evdata.editable)` I got undefined.

EVENT OBJECT:

```
{"id":"8_1","start":"2024-02-22 20:24","end":"2024-02-23 20:24","title":"Eileen","editable":true,"backgroundColor":"#40FF00","textColor":"#000000"}
```

CODE:

```
    eventClick: function(info) {
        console.log(info.event.id)
        let evdata = calendar.getEventById( info.event.id )
        console.log(evdata)
    }
```

CONSOLE LOG:

```
8_1 calendars.js:228
Object { _context: {…}, _def: {…}, _instance: {…} }
_context: Object { viewTitle: "18 Feb – 24 Feb", calendarApi: {…}, dispatch: dispatch(action)
, … }
_def: Object { title: "Eileen", publicId: "8_1", defId: "232", … }
allDay: false
defId: "232"
extendedProps: Object {  }
groupId: ""​​
hasEnd: true​​
interactive: undefined​​
publicId: "8_1"​​
recurringDef: null
​​sourceId: "16"
​​title: "Eileen"
​​ui: Object { startEditable: true, durationEditable: true, backgroundColor: "#40FF00", … }
​​url: ""
​​<prototype>: Object { … }
​_instance: Object { instanceId: "233", defId: "232", range: {…}, … }
​<prototype>: Object { … }
calendars.js:230
```